# Binding keyboard shortcuts to GLCanvas in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, wxpython

Is it possible to bind keyboard shortcuts (like `Ctrl+z` to Undo, `Ctrl+Shift+z` to Redo, `Ctrl+c`, `Ctrl+v`, etc.) to GLCanvas in wxpython? If so, can someone provide a minimal example, maybe something like drawing a sphere on single-click and then Undo and Redo with a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

```
import wx
from wx import glcanvas

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='test')
        self.gl = MyCanvasBase(self)
        self.Show()

class MyCanvasBase(glcanvas.GLCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        glcanvas.GLCanvas.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyDown) # for wx.WANTS_CHARS
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)

    def OnKeyDown(self, evt):
        keycode = evt.GetKeyCode()
        print keycode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    Frame = myFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
    app.Destroy()
```

(edit) control+c etc can be captured by setting window style to wx.WANTS_CHARS. I made changes to use that style.

This is my attempt to make a minimum example of capturing key down events but without cube.

Have you looked at wxphython demo? That is one of the best learning sources of wxpython. If you install [wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.12.1.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.12.1.exe/download), you will find an OpenGL sample code with a cube that you can rotate with mouse.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But the sample you provided does not capture any shortcut (combination of keys like `ctrl + key`) it only captures a single key. I will also give a try to `wx.EVT_CHAR`.

Comment: I somehow missed that you need ctrl+C etc. Yes, EVT_CHAR is the way to go but you will need to set WANTS_CHARS style to your widget. I edited my code in the answer.